# Use value in directive in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have a `timelineItem` directive that I call like so:

```
<div class="activity-header" timeline-item ng-click="vm.toggle();">
    something: {{spinner}}
```

In the directive I have a `spinner` value:

```
let spinner = false;
```

And inside a function in the directive I have:

```
function toggleHeightOfItem(timelineItem) {

    spinner = true;
```

But the `{{spinner}}` binding doesn't do anything. I guess because the scope of the `timelineItem` directive is only the html element it's declared on.

Is it possible to use a value set in a directive on a different element?

Comment: you can use `service` for it

Comment: Yea but I would to encapsulate everything in 1 directive.

Comment: how you have defined the scope?

Comment: Initialize a variable on `$rootscope`  use it on any HTML element, modify that variable in the `directive`'s scope by injecting `$rootscope` to it

Comment: Can you make a Plunker? It will be easier to see how it all fits together.

Comment: @Peter Boomsma share the directive code pls

Comment: @Sophie was that a question to me?

Comment: No, sorry - that was for @PeterBoomsma